# JavaScript declaring function in or outside 'each' loop

Tags: javascript, function

I dont have problem, just a question to someone who rly good know js. Is it better to declare and run a function in 'each loop' or better declare it outside and then run it in loop? Somewhere I read that if function is declared in each loop JS compiler processes that declaration the same number of time as the loop will run, but when you declare function outside the loop JS processes it just one time and then can easy run it each time in loop. Is that a true and its better to declare function outside the loop or thats no difference for JS language and code execution will take the same amount of time in both cases?

Comment: the reference is only once handed over, as any other call of a function.

Comment: It depends entirely on your code and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Rarely makes sense to declare functions inside a loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that a function declared in a loop isn't one function, it's as many functions as there are iterations of the loop. It's not true that that is better or worse than having a single function outside the loop.

Sometimes that's exactly what you want, for example if you want a closure for variables from inside your loop:

```js
// Creates 5 functions and calls them 500 ms apart
for ( let i = 1; i <= 5; i ++ ) {
    setTimeout( log_i, i*500 );
    function log_i ( ) {
        console.log( i );
    }
}
```

or

```js
// Creates 5 functions and calls them 500 ms apart
[1,2,3,'foo','bar'].forEach( function ( x, i ) {
    setTimeout( log_x, (i+1)*500 );
    function log_x ( ) {
        console.log( x );
    }
} );
```

It's the same with regular objects and even variables that just hold a primitive. If you need a different one for each iteration you must declare it in the loop (with `let` or `const`). If you can share one across all iterations you don't need to make a copy for every iteration, but for small objects and primitives you definitely should make a copy anyway if it makes your code cleaner.

For very large objects and functions that can be shared across all iterations you're usually better off creating it outside the loop, but I stress that it would need to be a ***very*** large object or a loop with several thousand iterations to really matter.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer to declare functions outside of loops since, as you've already noted, they are processed just one time. Since the nature of a loop is to iterate, JS will constantly call and create the function. This may result in performance issues. However, it is not to say that you should never use the approach. It all depends on your program's architecture and logic.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring the function in each loop does not make any sense. You can declare the function outside of the loops and eventually pass different parameters for each loop calling the outside declared function.